# data frame add column with conditionnaly count frequency based

Tags: r, dataframe, counter, frequency

I've got dataframe like this

```
#dt
#   a b c
#1: a 1 d
#2: a 1 d
#3: b 0 b
#4: b 1 d
#5: b 0 b
```

And what I'd like to receive is columnt with counter for each row number of rows which meets criteria like this: b=1 and c = d

```
#dt
#   a b c counter
#1: a 1 d 2
#2: a 1 d 2
#3: b 0 d 1
#4: b 1 d 1
#5: b 0 b 0
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Would the same condition apply to all rows in the data frame or will there possibly be different conditions on some/all rows?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the `counter` for every `a`? `df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(counter = sum(b == 1 & c == 'd'))
` ? How is the last value 0, should it be 1 ?

Comment: It would be the same condition

Comment: But groupby would change size of df, doesn't it? And I need just new column for each row

Comment: Ok..check your `c` column for your input and output, they are different.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dt =  data.frame(a = c("a","a","b","b","b"),
                 b= c(1,1,0,1,0),
                 c = c("d","d","b","d","b"))
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(counter = (b == 1) +( c == "d") )
```

Comment: something like this, but for b value in column a it gives 2, how to improve it, should be just 1

Comment: If you want rows where all two conditions verified to be one, try this:                               ``` dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(counter =  as.numeric(((b == 1) & ( c == "d")))) ```

Answer (score 0):

I've used @FALL Gora answer

```
dt %>% mutate(counter = as.numeric(((b == 1) & ( c == "d"))))
```

but I've added

```
dt %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(counter1=sum(counter))
```

and it works now